# Run kmeans text clustering with pytorch in gpu to create more than 1000 clusters

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, k-means

I am trying to implement kmeans clustering using kmeans-pytorch but I am getting memory error when I am try to create more than 10 clusters

My dataset is having 7000 text records

Here is my code snippet

```
import torch

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

from kmeans_pytorch import kmeans

text_data = #list of 7000 records 

# Preprocess the data

vectorizer =        TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text_data)

# Convert sparse matrix to PyTorch tensor

X = torch.Tensor(X.toarray())

# Move the data to the GPU

X = X.cuda()

# Run k-means clustering on the GPU
k = 1000

cluster_assignments, centroids = kmeans(X, k,device=torch.device('cuda'))
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at alloc_cpu.cpp:73] . DefaultCPUAllocator: can't allocate memory: you tried to allocate 41359010000 bytes. Error code 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use batching; unfortunately, K-means-pytorch currently does not support batching. You can create your batches and find the centers independently, as defined in the [original repo](https://github.com/subhadarship/kmeans_pytorch/blob/master/batch_processing.ipynb), or incorporated, as defined in the [ray](https://raynardj.github.io/ray/docs/kmean_torch), and [fast_pytorch_kmenas](https://github.com/DeMoriarty/fast_pytorch_kmeans/blob/master/fast_pytorch_kmeans/kmeans.py). The second approach will be more coherent than the first one.